# MqttMsgSubscribe.cs not found Error in Visual Studio 2019 (C#)

Tags: c#, mqtt

I have a weird error, with the following code:

```
MqttClient mClient = null;   
string[] topics = { "topic1", "topic1", "topic3" , "topic4"};

mClient = new MqttClient("127.0.0.1");
mClient.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

if (!mClient.IsConnected) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error Connecting to message broker...");
    return;
}

 Client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += MClient_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
 byte[] qosLevels = { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE,
 MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE };
 mClient.Subscribe(topics, qosLevels);
```

With 4 strings `({ "topic1", "topic1", "topic3" , "topic4"})`  i have the `MqttMsgSubscribe.cs` not found error but with 3 `({ "topic1", "topic1", "topic3"})` the app works just fine without any errors, can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `topics` array has 4 items, but `qosLevels` only 3 :)
The items counts in these arrays should be exactly the same.

So, do this:

```
byte[] qosLevels = { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE,
                     MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE,
                     MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE,
                     MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE };
```